# Possible to get "value of address" in python?

Tags: python, cpython, python-internals

In the following, I can see that when adding an integer in python, it adds the integer, assigns that resultant value to a new memory address and then sets the variable to point to that memory address:

```
>>> a=100
>>> id(a)
4304852448
>>> a+=5
>>> id(a)
4304852608
```

Is there a way to see what the value is at the (old) memory address 4304852448 (0x10096d5e0) is? For example: `value_of(0x10096d5e0)`

Comment: Why would it overwrite the memory location when garbage collection happens? How would that be useful? Also this is not part of the Python language specification so you might want to add the tag for the specific implementation that you are referring to (probably CPython).

Comment: @a_guest -- thanks. Yes I'm jus looking to see the address before/after garbage collection and all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> it adds the integer, assigns that resultant value to a new memory address

No; the *object that represents* the resulting value *has* a different memory address. Typically this object is created on the fly, but specifically for integers (which are immutable, and for some other types applying a similar optimization) the object may already exist and be reused.

> Is there a way to see what the value is at the (old) memory address 4304852448 (0x10096d5e0) is?

This question is not well posed. First off, "memory addresses" in this context are virtualized, possibly more than once. Second, in the Python model, addresses do not "have values". They are potentially the location of objects, which in turn represent values.

That said: at the location of the previous `id(a)`, the old object will still be present if and only if it has not been garbage-collected. For this, it is sufficient that some other reference is held to the object. (The timing of garbage collection is implementation-defined, but the reference CPython implementation implements garbage collection by reference counting.)

You are not, in general, entitled to examine the underlying memory directly (except perhaps with some kind of process spy that has the appropriate permissions), because Python is just not that low-level of a language. (As in @xprilion's answer, the CPython implementation provides a lower-level memory interface via `ctypes`; however, the code there is effectively doing an unsafe cast.)

If you did (and assuming CPython), you would **not** see a binary representation of the integer `100` in the memory location indicated by calling `id(a)` the first time - you would see instead the first word of the `PyObject` struct used to implement objects in the C code, which would usually be the refcount, but could be a pointer to the next live heap object in a [reference-tracing Python build](https://docs.python.org/3/using/configure.html#cmdoption-with-trace-refs) (if I'm reading [it](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/object.h) correctly).

Once it's garbage-collected, the contents of that memory are *again* undefined. They depend on the implementation, and even specifically for the C implementation, they depend on what the standard library free() does with the memory. (Normally it will be left untouched, because there is no reason to zero it out and it takes time to do so. A debug build might write special values into that memory, because it helps detect memory corruption.)

Comment: I agree with the unsafe part of my answer. It might answer the exact question here but it is important for enthusiasts to read this answer as well to understand what's happening under the hood. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to dereference the memory address, much like the pointers used in C/C++. The following code might help you -

```
import ctypes

a = 100
b = id(a)

print(b, ": ", a)

a+=5
print(id(a), ": ", a)

print(ctypes.cast(b, ctypes.py_object).value)
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
140489243334080 :  100
140489243334240 :  105
100
```

The above example establishes that the value stored in the previous address of `a` remains the same.

Hope this answers the question. Read @Karl's answer for more information about what's happening in the background - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58468810/2650341

Comment: You're right that there is actually access to the raw memory in the reference C implementation of Python. I have edited my answer to reflect this.